# Yii list of subdomains with CHtml link

Tags: php, url, yii, hyperlink, subdomain

How can i get a list of subdomain links with this code?

```
<?php echo CHtml::link($language, $this->getOwner()->createAbsoluteUrl('', $params)) ?>
```

this output is: `mydomain.com/page/blabla`

what i need is: `blabla.mydomain.com/page`

thanx

Answer (score 0):

You need to create route

```
"http://blabla.".$domain."/page"=>'blabla/page'
```

than you can use

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('blabla/page');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = "mydomain.com/page/blabla";
$arr = preg_split('/page\//',$x);
echo $arr[1].".".$arr[0]."page";
```